# NHibernate get collection from object

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a question. I want to get collection from object
When I try

```
 UserProfile user = _session.Query<UserProfile>()
                            .Where(x => x.Email == email)
                            .FirstOrDefault();
```

user has a collection of roles and it is OK. but when I try this:

```
 IList<UserRole> role = _session.Query<UserProfile>()
                                .Where(x => x.Email == email)
                                .Select(x => x.Roles).FirstOrDefault();
```

it doesn't work I get an error :

```
 could not execute query[SQL: SQL not available]
```

Comment: Please provide your Fluent mappings. And the inner exception (If there is one).

Comment: only one error is  HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
           .Table("UsersInRoles")
           .ParentKeyColumn("UserID")
           .ChildKeyColumn("RoleID")
           .LazyLoad()
           .Cascade.SaveUpdate();

Comment: Have you tried something like IList<UserRole> role = _session.Query<UserProfile>().Where(x => x.Email == email).SelectMany(x => x.Roles).FirstOrDefault(); ?

Comment: @user1644160 try updating the question rather  than adding stuff in the comments

Answer (score 0):

try writing you query like this

var roles = (from u in _session.Query from r in u.Roles select r).ToList();